# Writing txt-file float

Tags: python, list, for-loop, file-io

Now I have this kind of code:

```
    for s,h,v,r in zip(lopullinen, yksilo, osallistumiset, pistemaarat):
        tulostuksia.write(str(s) + ";".join(h) + ";" + str(r) + ";" + ";".join(str(v)) + "/7" + "\n")
```

and it gives this kind of output:

```
tunnus;nimi;sarja;juoksu-60m;pituushyppy;kuulantyonto;korkeushyppy;aitajuoksu-60m;seivashyppy;juoksu-1000m;kokonaispisteet;lajeja
101;Vertti Veteraaniurheilija;M70;709;651;750;806;850;759;801;5326;7/7
41;Severi Seitsenottelija;M;603;551;600;555;559;655;700;4223;7/7
42;Seppo Seitsenottelija;M;661;750;700;610;505;502;700;4428;7/7
43;Ylermi Yleisurheilija;M;603;601;700;655;661;555;500;4275;7/7
60;K. Keskeyttäjä;M40;603;601;-;-;-;-;-;1204;2/7
61;Yrjänä Yleisurheilija;M40;559;500;650;701;603;655;650;4318;7/7
```

But I would like to have those numbers to be float-types. Like this:

```
101;Vertti Veteraaniurheilija;M70;709.0;651.0;750.0;806.0;850.0;759.0;801.0;5326;7/7
```

Thouse numbers come from the list yksilo, which contains numbers from class. If i change it there to be float(when adding to the list), and from that for loop above ";".join(str(h)). It gives me output where the ";" is between every number(7;0;9;.;0; etc...) And if i don't put the str(h) in there, it gives "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found".

Is there an easy way to get those numbers to be formed 709.0 instead of 709.

Comment: Why aren't you using csv module for this?

Comment: replace the `'\n'` at the end with a `';'`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
'%f' % value
```

instead of the simple

```
str(value)
```

But the `str(value)` should already have given you `'4.0'` if the `value` had been a float in the beginning.  So maybe you need to convert that value to a float first:

```
str(float(value))
```

Also, if you need to keep the `-` values, you will have to check for these as well.  So in your example, use

```
tulostuksia.write(
  '%s%s;%s;%s%s' % (
    s,
    ";".join(h),
    r,
    ";".join('-' if vi == 'i' else str(float(vi)) for vi in v),
    "/7\n")
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, the list have also those '-' marks, and with that it gives me TypeError: a float is required.

Answer (score 0):

If `h` is a list `[709.0, 651.0]` then `str(h)` gives you `"[709.0, 651.0]"` and `';'.join(str(h))`, as you've seen, will iterate over the characters in the string, rather than the values in the list.

Instead, try `';'.join(map(str, h))`. This converts each item in the list *individually* to a string (whether it's a `'-'` or a `float`), then `join`s the resulting iterable/list (depending on Python version) of strings.

Example:

```
>>> print(";".join(map(str, ["-", 123.4, 567.8, "-", "-", 9.0])))
-;123.4;567.8;-;-;9.0
```